# Rendering html on npm start

Tags: node.js, express, npm, html5-video

I have created one project which has index.html and script.js file. So i have done npm init -y to get package.json. If i explicitly double click the index.html file it is opening it normally and functions as i want but if i do with express as res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './index.html')); it is not functioning properly. So i want to write an start script in a such way that it should directly run index.html

```
i have tried this 
router.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
})
But is is not functioning well. It is just rendering raw html in normal function it is asking me for permission to access camera and microphone. But here it asking nothing. 

{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "VideoCall App",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "AkshayK",
  "license": "MIT"
}


I want to render index.html when i do npm start.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have made one application with this same functionality for you. You
>   can check it here.  https://github.com/RajatKaushik/Camera-App

Express is Middleware for handling http requests, you will have to make a  ***GET*** request from the browser. Once you make the request your express app will match the path and will respond back with the file(index.html) in your case.

So, If you want to deliver the index.html file on the browser, do the following steps:-

- Run your node application using `node [YOUR_FILE_NAME.js]` (node script.js).
- If your express server is running on port **4200**, then make the request to

> localhost:4200/

As that's the path that you have for responding back with the index.html file.

I think the reason why your Camera and Microphone is not working is because the code that initiate that is in some script file that you have include in your HTML file as `<script src="index.js">` but you are not delivering that file using express.

You can use the following code snippet to deliver that static files needed.

```
app.use(express.static('__dirname' + '/public'), () => {
        console.log('Request Recived');
    });
```

where the public is the folder in which your `index.js` file is present.

> I have made one application with this same functionality for you. You
>   can check it here.  https://github.com/RajatKaushik/Camera-App

Comment: I have done router.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
}) yes it is rendering the html but not functioning well means if i double click the html file explicitly thne it asks for permission to use camera and microphone but here it is not asking anything that is the problem

Comment: Are you using a separate javascript file that you are including in your html as <script src="./index.js">? If you then you will have to deliver that js file as well to the browser

Comment: I have following files Index.html, script.js and something.min.js in index.html in script tag i have used something.in.js file. Ok. Now i have created another file that is index.js in that i have following code const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');


app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
});

app.listen(process.env.port || 3000);

console.log('Running at Port 3000');

Comment: It is rendering the index.html but not asking for permissions to access camera and microphone.

Comment: Please check the edited answer, I have attached one reference implementation for you. Steps to run the application are also there.